# How to cope with long texts in menus?

Tags: menu, mega-menu

we have a standard horizontal menu bar with submenu items with long texts. These texts are really long and we can not make them short, every word is necessary. Like:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdtq3O.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

I have looked at solutions like megamenus (not suitable for us) or ellipsis. Do you think use of ellipses can mislead user? Or do you have any other solution? By the way we are using Primefaces, if you reccommend any component from Primefaces..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are those titles for articles that people can edit for instance? I'm just trying to get some context on what that information is. Is that information shareable between different people, or is that private for only the user who created those editable documents?

Comment: no they are not editable. They are stable menu items.

Comment: Oh, I was confused because the drop down menu looked like it was coming from the edit category. Can you still provide some context as to why they are long? Is it just the jargon you guys are using, or is it user generated content? If so (user generated content), can others see those lengthy menu items?

Comment: It is long because the domain requires it. The terminology/jargon of the domain makes it impossible to shorten the phrases.. The content is absolutely generated by us.

Comment: So this is just a regular menu, nothing dynamic about it?

Comment: Yes, exactly.. 
I think, there shouldn't be minimum length in comments :)

Comment: I am not buying that you need very long text to differentiate menu items.  The menu name does not need to describe the item.

Comment: I agree with @Blam. I still think you should try to fight for shorter menu links

Comment: @Blam OK, then do you have any recommendation to shorten "OCSP and Timestamp Certificate Operations" menu item?

Comment: The way you shorten is to remove words and letters.

Comment: I don't have domain knowledge, but from a short google, I'd expect you'd be able to just write "Timestamp Cert Ops (OCSP)". Not too pretty, but people looking for the phrase will know where to look. You can have the full title in whatever window/page pops up when you select it, to affirm it was the right choice. Maybe even leave out OCSP all together. Or even just "Timestamp Certificates". The idea is not to be 100% precise, the idea is to help people find where they want to go. Most OSes allow tool tips on menu items, if you want to show the long form somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Long menu items are not necessarily a problem, it's how they get *presented* that can sometime make them appear awkward and not well thought out.

Consider the worst case scenario of dealing with menu items that are too wide for the screen.

A few options might be to:

- truncate the text (not ideal)
- use an ellipsis at a suitable point (beginning, middle, but not the end)
- multi-line items

An ellipsis is common in menu items when recently used files have long path names, but don't use one at the end of the text as that could be misinterpreted.

You might think multi-line text is not common in menus - until perhaps you consider the ubiquitous mega drop down menu common on the web, or the panel-like popups used by Microsoft Office and other applications.

In these cases, the menus have been *designed* for chunks of text, with appropriate white space and grouping. Perhaps something like these examples below could be used as inspiration to solve your problem more elegantly:

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I think I'll go with long texts in menu items separated by gaps from other items.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I don't think it's a big problem, as long as you provide a clear distinction between where one starts and where it ends.

Although I would say you should keep menus easy to scan. Having extensive menu names could cause some confusion.

Here is what I'm thinking for a design (lines in-between):

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fd9QTA.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

I still highly suggest that you shorten those for the sake of the IA and even SEO. Good SEO and clean URLS also make the experience really fun and memorable.

Comment: Do you suggest lines in between the menu items?

Comment: About the SEO: Since the target system will not be in intranet (it will not be in internet), we do not have SEO-related requirements. Thanks for reminding, though..